# Using sqlContext.sql for sub queries in scala

Tags: mysql, scala

I have created the following HIVE code and require to translate it to use in scala.  From what I understand we need to use **sqlContext.sql**
The examples available online only have simple select statements.Like the example below.

For example to run a simple sql query in scala:

```
val tableA = sqlContext.sql("Select * from game");
```

I can't seem to use the same syntax for the code below.What is the syntax to translate the code below to fit the above usage.

```
 DROP TABLE ADW.TERA_BARCODE_LOOKUP_TABLE_RAW ;

   CREATE TABLE ADW.TERA_BARCODE_LOOKUP_TABLE_RAW AS
   SELECT CAST(BRCDE_REF_I  AS STRING) AS BARCODE,
   MAX(TRIM(GST_SRC_ID)) AS GST_SRC_ID,MAX(SRC_ACTV_TS) AS SRC_ACTV_TS
   FROM

(SELECT RANKED.*
FROM
(SELECT BRCDE_REF_I,GST_SRC_ID,SRC_ACTV_TS,
RANK() over (partition by BRCDE_REF_I ORDER BY SRC_ACTV_TS DESC) AS RANK
FROM
ADW.GST_SRC_ID_BRCDE_LKUP_TABLE   X
WHERE   UPPER(X.CURR_ACTV_F) = 'Y' AND TRIM(X.GST_SRC_ID) IN
(SELECT TRIM(GST_SRC_I) FROM ADW.CANDIDATE_GST_ID_SRC_TABLE GROUP BY TRIM(GST_SRC_I))
) RANKED
WHERE RANKED.RANK = 1  ) X
GROUP BY BRCDE_REF_I ;
```

Comment: What is the error? I would add a `BEGIN TRAN` and `COMMIT` to the beginning and end of the mysql code and try to run it again.

Answer (score 2):

There are two SQL commands, and because Apache Hive [doesn't support *BEGIN* and *COMMIT*](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+Transactions) best option for you will be to put it into two commands.

You have not posted your error. I assumed you could also got error on `DROP TABLE`, so changed it to `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`.

Also, in Scala to use multiline strings, you have to wrap them with `"""`, not `"`.

```
sqlContext.sql("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ADW.TERA_BARCODE_LOOKUP_TABLE_RAW")
sqlContext.sql("""
CREATE TABLE ADW.TERA_BARCODE_LOOKUP_TABLE_RAW AS
SELECT CAST(BRCDE_REF_I  AS STRING) AS BARCODE,
MAX(TRIM(GST_SRC_ID)) AS GST_SRC_ID,MAX(SRC_ACTV_TS) AS SRC_ACTV_TS
FROM
(SELECT RANKED.*
FROM
(SELECT BRCDE_REF_I,GST_SRC_ID,SRC_ACTV_TS,
RANK() over (partition by BRCDE_REF_I ORDER BY SRC_ACTV_TS DESC) AS RANK
FROM
ADW.GST_SRC_ID_BRCDE_LKUP_TABLE   X
WHERE   UPPER(X.CURR_ACTV_F) = 'Y' AND TRIM(X.GST_SRC_ID) IN
(SELECT TRIM(GST_SRC_I) FROM ADW.CANDIDATE_GST_ID_SRC_TABLE GROUP BY TRIM(GST_SRC_I))
) RANKED
WHERE RANKED.RANK = 1  ) X
GROUP BY BRCDE_REF_I
""")
```